# Find employee IDs that have a single SSN entry that is null or multiple SSN entries that are not equal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains an `employeeID` and an SSN field.  I am trying to filter out all records with the following critera:

All employees that have a single SSN entry who's value is null

All employees that have greater than one SSN entry

The following shows the three scenarios

```
ID          SSN
1           000000000
1           NULL

ID          SSN
1           000000000
1           111111111

ID          SSN
1           NULL
```

Here is the table definition:  I am populating this table withe data from a Sybase Data base

http://tinypic.com/r/65wvhi/6

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: I thinks you should normalize your data and this query would be a lot easier..

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any control over the source data

Comment: Can you post your schema, I'm not really understanding your example data.

Answer (score 2):

```
select  employeeID 
from    YourTable
group by 
        employeeID
having  count(case when SSN is null then 1 end) > 0
        or count(distinct SSN) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use aggregation for this, with a `having` clause:

```
 select e.id
 from ssns e
 group by e.id
 having (count(*) = 1 and count(ssn) = 0) or  -- first condition
        count(*) > 1   -- second condition
```